# angularjs ng-style with calculations of width in html tag

Tags: angularjs

I need to calculate the with depending on a scope value. 
I've been trying something like this:

```
    <div class="scene" ng-style="{ 'width': '(illustrationStyles.Width /5000) * 100' % }">
```

But i can't get it to work. I can't really find any good examples of this either.

Is it possible to do calculations in ng-style?

Answer (score 1):

You should need to remove single quotes and add percern sign at last.

Replace

```
<div class="scene" ng-style="{ 'width': '(illustrationStyles.Width /5000) * 100' % }">`
```

With

```
<div class="scene" ng-style="{ 'width': (illustrationStyles.Width /5000) * 100 + '%' }">
```

I hope that will work.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your calculations in the controller

var calValue = ((illustrationStyles.Width /5000) * 100) + %

Answer (score 0):

removes the extra single quote, and adds the percent at end:

```
<div class="scene" ng-style="{ 'width': ((illustrationStyles.Width /5000) * 100) + '%' }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value must be in between quotes.

```js
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Style with calc";
  $scope.illustrationStyles = {
    Width : 4000
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
    <div ng-style="{'width': (illustrationStyles.Width /5000) * 100 + '%', 'background-color': 'red'}">
      {{ title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```